# What are the barriers that prevent widespread adoption of formal methods?

Tags: development-process, code-quality, formal-methods

Formal methods can be used to specify, prove and generate code for an application. This is less prone to errors - thus mostly used in safety/critical programs.

Why don't we use it more often for everyday programming, or in web applications, etc... ?

References :

- [Formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods)
- [B Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-Method)
- [Hoare Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic)

Comment: see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)

Comment: We could build houses with 5 foot thick walls - like medieval castles.  Most of the time, that would be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: You can try applying formal methods to a web dev project, and see how it goes. Most likely you'll notice that you're pouring lots of effort into a low-value activity. Contrast that with quick smoke testing, which will already capture many bugs. Interestingly, static type systems are a simple kind of proof system, yet especially web development shuns those languages (instead preferring highly dynamic languages like Ruby, PHP, or JavaScript). Correlation does not imply causation, but it gives pause to thought.

Comment: So you'd prefer to specify in a specification language instead of programming in a programming language ?  Ok, you'll be able to prove that it works according to the specs.  But how are you going to prove that the specification reflect the true problem ?

Comment: @Christophe  "you'll be able to prove that it works according to the specs", isn't it what we want?

Comment: @toto the question is: doing the things right (work according to the specs) or doing the right things (having the good specs).  While in theory the spec is what we want, in practice we rarely know for sure what is really needed:  https://beyssonmanagement.com/2012/10/29/who-knows-what-the-customer-really-wants/

Comment: For projects that are extremely sensitive to potential errors, writing requirements/code at the amortized rate of one line of production code per person per month might well make sense. (The test code doesn't count, nor does the metacode doesn't count, nor do the formalized requirements. Production code only. With formal methods, it's easy to have the cost be the equivalent of a line of code per person per month.) For the vast majority of projects, "perfect is the enemy of good enough."

Comment: For those who are disappointed that this is closed there's now a great blog post: [Why Don't People Use Formal Methods?](https://www.hillelwayne.com/post/why-dont-people-use-formal-methods/)

Comment: and the accompanying [Hacker News discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18965274)

Comment: I'm still disappointed it was closed, all the same. It's... such a shame, honestly. If there are concrete, widespread barriers to entry or adoption, then there are answers that fit here. But there's an aversion towards questions that aren't immediately touchable, if you will, which is honestly sad.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An Engineer is a person who can do with a dollar what any idiot can do with 10.

Resource constraints, budget constraints, time constraints, they are all important.

Developing software using formal methods is usually significantly more expensive and takes much longer than without. Also, for many projects, the hardest part is understanding the business requirements. All that using formal methods buys you in that case is proof that your code corresponds 100% to your incomplete and incorrect understanding of the business requirements.

For that reason, the use of formal methods, proofs, program verification and similar techniques is typically limited to "stuff that matters", i.e. avionics software, control systems for medical equipment, power plants, etc.

Comment: I'd also add that putting formal methods into the programming language is an area of active research currently i.e. is not yet ready for mainstream

Comment: I accept this answer, but I also wanted an approach on why formal methods are still considered 'expensive' and 'time consuming', especially when we know how expensive is maintenance and code tracking/debugging on big projects.

Comment: TDD & BDD are approaches built on the principles of Hoare logic, a foundation of formal approaches.  They improve efficiency not detract from it.

Comment: @jk. formal methods have been around for decades and their use in appropriate domains is actually well advanced.

Comment: @toto In fact, bugs, and human injuries and deaths, caused by bugs, are more expensive and time consuming than formal methods, most likely. For the space between "super critical code" and "stupid web app" some people are pushing for LIght formal methods, which are simply some subset of formal methods used on some subset of code, and generally favoring the friendlier tools.

Comment: @toto Proofs are really, REALLY hard. A lot of things mathematicians take for granted in proofs doesn't apply in programs. For example, in C++, addition is not associative: `(-1 + 1) + INT_MAX = INT_MAX`, `-1 + (1 + INT_MAX)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @toto: The reason they are considered "expensive" and "time-consuming" is because we can look at projects that are developed using formal methods and empirically verify that those projects take much longer to develop. Look at the development time of seL4/L4.verified, for example, compared to *any* other implementation of L4.

Comment: @Hovercouch Proofs are hard but automated proofs are not hard. It is hard to educate people to create more easily proven languages, and to annotate code with contracts.

Comment: Model checking is a formal method that can be very cost effective and worthwhile. It is used a lot in the industry. You don't need to know anything about proofs to use it, you just need to give an abstract description of the system and the expected properties, and the model checker (e.g. Alloy, TLA+, etc.) will verify them automatically for you.

Comment: @FrankHileman wouldn't the proofs are hard issue be solved by having strong automated provers? Assuming we have good spec, what is the biggest contribution ATPs bring to the table?

Comment: @Pinocchio Theorem provers need to be fast, so that people use them as often as they compile. The warnings must be easy to understand. That implies the languages are designed to be easy to create proofs for -- functional languages are often better. It also implies that the prover and language development go hand in hand with compiler development, at the commercial level (which rarely happens now). Even with a poor/missing spec,  there are many things that can be checked. Eventually we will consider non proven code to be from the dark ages, and rightly fear it.

Answer (score 14):

#### To program or not to program?

To solve a problem with a software product, after having an understanding of the requirements, you can **EITHER** write a program using programming languages **OR** specify the program using a formal language and use code generation tools. The latter just adds a level of abstraction.

#### Doing the things right or doing the right things?

The formal approach gives you a proof that your software works according to the specifications. So your product does the things right. But does it do the right things?

The requirements on which you are working might be incomplete or ambiguous.  They could even be buggy. In the worst case, the real needs are not even expressed. But a picture is worth a thousand words, just google images for "What the customer wants", for example from [this article](https://beyssonmanagement.com/2012/10/29/who-knows-what-the-customer-really-wants/):

[image]

#### The cost of formality

In a perfect world, you would have fully detailed and perfect requirements from the beginning. You could then fully specify your software.  If you'd go for formal, your code would be generated automatically so that you would be more productive.  Productivity gains would offset the cost of the formal tools. And everybody would now using formal methods. So why isn't it?

In practice, this is rarely the reality! This is why so many [waterfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model) projects failed, and why [iterative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development) development methods (agile, RAD, etc) took the lead: they can handle incomplete and imperfect requirements, designs and implementations and refine them until they are fine.

And here comes the point. With formal methods, each iteration requires to have a completely consistent formal spec. This requires careful thinking and additional work, because formal logic is not forgiving and doesn't like incomplete thoughts.  Simple throw-away experiments become expensive under this constraint.  And so does each iteration that would lead to backtracking (e.g. an idea that didn't work, or a requirement that was misunderstood).

#### In practice

When not obliged to use formal methods for legal or contractual reasons, you can also achieve very high quality without formal systems, for example by using [contract based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) and other good practices (e.g. code review, [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), etc...).  You'll not be able to prove that your software works, but your users will enjoy working software sooner.

#### *Update: measured effort*

In the October 2018 issue of [*Communications of the ACM*](https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2018/10) there is an interesting article about [*Formally verified software in the real world*](https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2018/10/231372-formally-verified-software-in-the-real-world/fulltext) with some estimates of the effort.

Interestingly (based on OS development for military equipment), it seems that producing formally proved software requires **3.3 times more effort** than with traditional engineering techniques.  So it's really costly.

On the other hand, it requires **2.3 times less effort to get high security software** this way than with traditionally engineered software if you add the effort to make such software certified at a high security level (EAL 7).  So if you have high reliability or security requirements there is definitively a business case for going formal.

> seL4 design and code development took two person-years. Adding up all serospecific proofs over the years comes to a total of 18 person-years for 8,700 lines of C code. In comparison, L4Ka::Pistachio, another microkernel in the L4 family, comparable in size to seL4, took six person-years to develop and provides no significant level of assurance. This means there is only a factor **3.3** between verified software and traditionally engineered software. According to the estimation method by Colbert and Boehm,8 a traditional Common Criteria EAL7 certification for 8,700 lines of C code would take more than 45.9 person-years. That means formal binary-level implementation verification is already more than a factor of **2.3** less costly than the highest certification level of Common Criteria yet provides significantly stronger assurance.

Comment: Contract based programming does use at least informal proofs.

Comment: @FrankHileman yes ! And the simple fact of clarifying   preconditions, postconditions and invariants greatly helps to review code efficiently, reduce errors, and systematise tests.

Comment: This should be the best answer by far.

Answer (score 1):

Every program in any language can be thought of as a formal specification (equivalent to some turning machine). Any higher level 'formal specification' to be used in proving formal correctness is also - just another program. But its (typically) a bad, incomplete, vague, insufficiently thought through program. And not coincidentally, typically written by people who don't know how to program (they are usually domain experts).

And so proving that one program is compatible (produces the same answers or however you characterize it)  with its higher level formal requirements, invariable comes down to how you resolve the ambiguities in the higher level formal specification. There is no good general purpose way to do that.

That mapping of high level requirements to lower level details is the gist of what real programming is about. It should not be surprising that the core work being done by a programmer reading and interpreting specifications cannot be replaced by hand-waving and saying 'now just see if this high level formal specification is complied to by this sample program'.

Even in the early days of logic programming, where this concept first seemed so promising (because both the high level specification and actual underlying programs could be written in the same language), this core problem proved intractable.